# Getting validation responce

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have an AJAX login form. I used CakePHP form helpers to create the form but not the error messages.

The forms data is sent to the controller:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        if($this->Auth->login()) {
            echo "logged In";
        } else {
            echo "Login Failed";
        }
        exit;
    }
}
```

I then have in my controller, a validation array:

```
public $validate = array(
    'AccountEmail' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Please Enter A Valid Email.'
        )
    ),
    'AccountPassword' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Please Enter A Valid Password.'
        )
    )
);
```

At the moment, if I fill in the form with random characters it echos out 'login Failed' which is good.

But how can I access the validation data too see what failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris, the model validation rules are only used when attempting to **Save** or **Update** data on the **User** model.

You could though still return the validation messages by validating the data in your controller. Something similar to:

```
/**
 * Set data against the data model
 */
$this->User->set($this->request->data);

/**
 * Validate data and return any error messages
 */
$errors = $this->User->validates();
```